# Why defined integral of x works

Tags: integration

I know this is duplicate, but I still struggling to understand why this particular example works:

If we check `integral of x dx`, we see it is parabola.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+x+dx

Then if we do it as `integral from 0 to 1 of x dx`

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+1+of+x+dx

Then it "magically" works and calculate precise area of 0.5 .

I know all about delta x and so on.

But how the parabola is related to straight line?

And how just subtracting two anti-derivatives, we got the area in question?

Comment: It seems that you "know all about delta x and so on", except what they mean...

Comment: It wasn’t obvious, historically, that the integral is related to the antiderivative of the function. This is what the fundamental theorem of calculus is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a triangle of width and height $x$ (instead of $1$). Isn't its area

$$A(x)=\frac{x\cdot x}2 ?$$

Now consider the trapezium formed by the verticals at $x=\dfrac12$ and $x=1$, the $x$ axis and the line $y=x$. Isn't is area given by the difference of two triangles of width/height $\frac12$ and $1$ ?

$$\left.A\right|_{\frac12}^1=\frac{1^2}2-\frac{\left(\frac12\right)^2}2.$$

---

The area of a shape can be recast as "the width times the average height", and in a discrete setting the average is "the sum over the number of values", which is what an integral computes in the continuous domain.